# Check if page is filterable

Tags: filter, filtered-nav, rwd

I'm building a store responsively and for the top navigation on a mobile I have an option to "filter" which should only be shown on pages which are filterable, such as the search results page, the catalog pages.

This is just a link with an id which makes a siderbar slide in/out. But the link only needs to be shown if there's actually something to filter.

I've tried looking in to the Catalog_Block_Layer class and there are a couple of methods which I thought might work, but don't. Such as:

```
Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer')->canShowBlock()
```

and

```
Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer')->canShowOptions()
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in your question are not working because by the time you call them `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer` might be not yet instantiated.

One dirty solution can be the following:

```
if (count(array_intersect($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(), array('catalog_category_layered', 'catalogsearch_result_index'))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did think that would be the reason why it wasn't working because I was using it in the header. But your solution seems to work fine, thanks.